# Point domain name to static IP

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, ubuntu, nameserver

I just got a cloud hosting (Ubuntu Server with LAMP) with my own static IP. How do I move the domain name of an existing web hosting account I have to that static IP? Do I need to have DNS server for that or do I need to hire a nameserver service just to pointing there?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many (most?) DNS registrars will provide you with free DNS hosting.

If this is true of your situation, and if your Web host is currently your DNS host, log into your DNS registration account and change the nameservers to point at your DNS registrar instead of your current Web host. (This'll ensure you can cancel the old account after moving your content and not suffer any DNS-related repercussions.)

At that point, you can create or modify the necessary records to point yourdomain.com to the IP of your new VPS!

Comment: Hi Cheeseprocedure, the current web hosting is at 123marbella.co.uk, the Nameservers are dns1.name-services.com and the registrar is Enom.com. How do I login there? Should I ask 123marbella to give me the login details for Enom? Thank you

Comment: Did you register the domain name yourself, or did 123marbella take care of it? If they registered it on your behalf, then yes, you'd need to get the necessary Enom credentials from them.

Comment: Yes, they did it all themselves. Thanks for your help mate!